# Im trying to get the max and min number without .max()/.min()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to get the maximum and minimum numbers between 3 numbers but my code doesnt work as intended or prints different numbers, why is this happening and how can i solve this please?

Thanks in advance.

```
var show=document.querySelectorAll('.show');
show[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var q5Value1=document.getElementById('q5Value1');
    var q5Value2=document.getElementById('q5Value2');
    var q5Value3=document.getElementById('q5Value3');
    var a5=document.getElementById('a5');
    q5Value1.addEventListener('change',function(){
        a5.style.opacity=0;
    })
    q5Value2.addEventListener('change',function(){
        a5.style.opacity=0;
    })
    q5Value3.addEventListener('change',function(){
        a5.style.opacity=0;
    })
    
    var setValueAndStyle = function(max,min){
        a5.innerHTML='Max: '+max+' Min: '+min;
        q5Value1.style.borderColor="unset";
        q5Value2.style.borderColor="unset";
        q5Value3.style.borderColor="unset";
        a5.style.opacity=1;
    }
    if(q5Value1.value==""){
        invalidEntry(q5Value1);
    }
    else if(q5Value2.value==""){
        invalidEntry(q5Value2);
    }
    else if(q5Value3.value==""){
        invalidEntry(q5Value3);
    }
    else if(q5Value1.value > q5Value2.value){
            if(q5Value2.value > q5Value3.value){
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value1.value , q5Value3.value);
            }
            else {
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value1.value , q5Value2.value)
            }
    }
    else if(q5Value2.value > q5Value1.value){
            if(q5Value1.value > q5Value3.value){
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value2.value , q5Value3.value);
            }
            else {
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value2.value , q5Value1.value)
            }
    }
    else if(q5Value3.value > q5Value1.value){
            if(q5Value1.value > q5Value2.value){
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value3.value , q5Value2.value);
            }
            else {
                setValueAndStyle(q5Value3.value , q5Value1.value)
            }
    }
})
```

jsfiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/dhgau09r/6/

EDIT:Dont mind the InvalidEntry function its just a function that i defined above but didnt include it in this version of code.

Comment: It's because the field values are strings, you have to convert them to numbers. You can use `Number(q5Value2)` or `parseInt(q5Value2)`

Comment: Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/dwg9fhbc/ 

@ahmed-elhoseny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in javascript you should do equality comparison with triple equal signs. Then in order to get the min and max without using the min/max functions you can do something like this:

```
let q1 = parseInt(q5Value1.value);
let q2 = parseInt(q5Value2.value);
let q3 = parseInt(q5Value3.value);

let max = q1;

if(max < q2) max = q2;
if(max < q3) max = q3;

let min = q1;
if(min > q2) min = q2;
if(min > q3) min = q3;

// do something with min and max
```